# Как сделать из созданного ХТМЛ-элемента строку js

Tags: javascript, строки

Пробовал найти ответы в гугле, но результаты вечно не те, что нужны... Наверное, я не совсем правильно формулирую вопрос, поэтому обращаюсь к знатокам за помощью.

Итак, проблема следующая:

```
function status() {
      let a = [ 'Status',]
      let span = document.createElement('span')
      span.className = "text6"
      span.style = "color: red"
      span.innerText = 'Ruined'
      let span2 = String(span)
      console.log('span', span)
      console.log('span2', span2)
      for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        a.push('<span class="text6" style="color: red">Ruined</span>')
      }
      return a;
    },
```

Есть у меня небольшая функция, которая создает заполненные ХТМЛ-элементы с тегами и прочей необходимой атрибутикой, а затем формирует из них массив, на основе которого уже позже будет строится таблица... Но вот проблема: если я оформляю данный тег строкой и просто пушу эту строку в массив, то все прекрасно работает, но если я пытаюсь сделать `createElement` то в массив добавляется такая вот запись `[object HTMLSpanElement]`...

Как я понимаю, проблема в том, что я создал элемент для добаления в DOM-дерево, а не строку... Я пытался преобразовать полученное значение в строку, но это тоже не помогло (переменная `span2`)...

Итак вопрос, как сделать так, чтобы результат выполнения  `a.push(span)` был таким же, как в `a.push('<span class="text6" style="color: red">Ruined</span>')`? Надеюсь, я понятно изложил свою мысль.

Comment: _при построении таблицы система выдает [object HTMLSpanElement]_ - проблема в том как ты строишь таблицу

Comment: span - у вас это node DOM, а строка, это строка. Вам надо менять ваш рендер(установку элемента в DOM). Покажите, как вы добавляете элементы в DOM дерево из массива

Comment: @SwaD, скорее всего что-то вроде `status().join('')` :)

Comment: @SwaD, к вопросу добавил саму функцию, которая публикует данные в таблицу и сам обьект с данными...

Comment: @SwaD, да :-D не угадал

Comment: Как `DataForTable` связан с `printDataTable`? И в `printDataTable` что за data? Т.е. не понятно, что лежит вот здесь `data[property[i]][k]`?

Comment: @SwaD, `DataForTable` в функции `printDataTable` и есть `data`, то есть под `data[property[i]][k]` подразумевается `DataForTable[property[i]][k]`. Но Grundy уже дал необходимый мне ответ, так что спасибо за помощь и беспокойство. Вопрос можно закрывать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Свойство `.innerText` при установке приводит аргумент к строке, так как передается элемент `span`, его строковая форма выглядит как `[object HTMLSpanElement]`

В данном случае лучше всего будет пересмотреть способ вывода элементов в таблицу, однако, получить разметку html элемента можно с помощью свойства [`.outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML)

```js
let span = document.createElement('span')
span.className = "text6"
span.style = "color: red"
span.innerText = 'Ruined'

var html = span.outerHTML;

console.log(html);
```

Comment: спасибо, все отлично заработало. Результат именно такой, как мне нужно было!

Comment: @drakoblack, но все равно, лучше либо сразу строками собирать все, либо везде элементы использовать. Не совсем понятно почему именно для статуса решил собирать элемент

Comment: это просто эксперимент. До этого я все строками делал, но это довольно неудобно и громоздко получается, а если элементы формировать через создание тегов, то получается довольно компактно, удобно для чтения и весьма просто вносить правки... Поэтому я подумываю над тем, чтобы переделать все подобные строки в такие конструкции...

Comment: когда там лишь одно слово и несколько свойств, может показаться, что это не совсем разумный подход, но когда смена свойств тега и его содержимое начнут активно меняться, это будет самое оно.

Comment: @drakoblack, я скорее имел ввиду что если ты работаешь с элементами - то и вставлять их надо как элементы, а сейчас получается - создаешь элементы в работаешь все равно со строкой

Comment: что я тут могу сказать. Возможно однажды подобные вещи будут и мне казаться самоочевидными. А пока я только учусь и "набиваю себе шишки" там, где Вы их уже давно набили.